# facebook instant game not working properly on local server

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

the app testing was working locally as well hosting. but suddenly it occurred error when run locally. but same project after hosting the facebook work fine. please would like share your experiences with facebook instant game for this issue. thank you very much.

[this is the error occured in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw7re.png)

Answer (score 0):

same problem here. All projects give exact same error. I think something went wrong on fb systems.